possible to streamline existing tags?
last week, i visited the site and found that there're 203 tags. to select an appropriate one amongst these options is stressful, imo.
so, can we streamline these tags into a healthier grid?
my first suggestion is:
have a new tag ”tech” for computer / tablet / phone, operation systems, apps, encoding / fonts / unicode related question, replacing the following tags:

software  (36)
fonts (31)
ime   (30)
technology    (18)
websites  (17)
input-methods (10)
technical (10)
multimedia    (9)
cc-cedict (7)
online    (5)
ocr   (1)

open for discussion :)

My opinion: Yes, tags really need to be streamlined!  However, users are not going to naturally think of the word "tech" when they're asking questions about IME, fonts, etc.
If a question is poorly tagged, there are often additional issues like poor titles, spelling and grammar errors, or it being off-topic yet not (yet) closed.  So they're often best off being individually edited (gradually [maybe 3-4 at a time] so as to not flood the front page), rather than bulk retag.
Going through these tags, these are my thoughts:

multimedia is already gone (it was a buzz word back in the 90s, but I feel people use it less nowadays); there are suitable alternative tags, like audio.  (I recall editing these questions yesterday maybe.)  Done.

ocr is also already gone.  Done.

online (5 Qs) should be edited away: it's too vague.  Done.  The questions are:

Are there online resourses that automatically translates English to classical Chinese?
What's the format of official "online" HSK tests?
When searching in Chinese, why do things always come up in traditional characters?
What does 'duang' mean in 'online Chinese'?
Is There A Chinese Version of Urban Slang Dictionary?


technology (18 Qs) also looks like an excessively vague tag: there are questions about online resources, software, hardware, and questions about Chinese words that relate to technology.  It's simply too unspecific for users to use.  It's clearer now:

For questions about terminology that pertains to applied sciences, as IT and software, electronics, engineering in general, medical sciences, etc. For pure science, use the [terminology] tag alone.


I'm fairly sure we don't need both input-methods and ime; maybe this would be a useful synonym.  (This probably deserves an independent meta post.)  Done.

technical doesn't seem too bad: it's for technical language, specific to some domain.  (Although maybe we could live without it; perhaps it's a "meta tag", like advanced.)  It was edited away here: What's the difference between [terminology] and [technical]? Burninate [technical]? Done.

cc-cedict is one I created anticipating asking a lot of CC-CEDICT definition questions, but they don't seem to be arising.  It's probably fine to merge it into definition: since most of the questions are mine, and I don't think anyone would miss it.  Done.

software, fonts, websites and ime (xor input-methods) seem reasonable to me; these are the kinds of words people will search for.  (Although I wonder how many questions about e.g. software get the tag software.)


The main challenge, I feel, is maintaining them.  It's not that difficult to change the tags so that they're correct momentarily, but ensuring they stay that way long-term is not easy.
In general, I encourage users to be active with retagging, editing, and curation in general:  If we make a mistake, it can be quickly fixed (there's lots of eyes).  If we leave the site neglected over time, it's a lot harder to fix.

I'm especially in favor of a [technical] tag to catch questions about terminology that belongs to specialized domains. It probably warrants its own meta post

my second suggestion is:
delete tags with 1, or 0 question tagged, such as:

ocr (1)
onomatopoeia (1)
quantifiers (1)
qing (1)
的 (1)
beijing-dialect (1)
riddle (1)
linguistics (1)
beginner (1)
character (0)
charcter  (0)
dialect (0)
hanoi (0)
kanji (0)
language-learning (0)
net-slang (0)
成語 (0)

sound reasonable?

The 0 Qs tags are synonyms (or will go away automatically).  [ocr] and [beginner] should already be gone.  At Japanese.SE, they use e.g. particle-の instead of, say, [particles] or [的].  I think it's a better system, and I've been thinking about suggesting it here (although there's some issues about simplified vs. traditional).

One other thing I should point out: single-use tags autodelete (unless they have a tag wiki).  If nothing changes, then [onomatopoeia], [quantifiers], [的], and [riddle] will autodelete.
